# IntelliJ doesn't detect source code for some Kotlin classes

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I don't understand why IntelliJ doesn't detect source code for some Kotlin classes. Let me show you an example:

Simple Spring WebFlux project. While debugging I wanted to go to each class, but when I tried to go into Mono.kt class, I saw

```
// IntelliJ API Decompiler stub source generated from a class file
// Implementation of methods is not available
```

Ok, maybe I didn't download the source code, but I see all sources[image]
But IntelliJ shows me this:

[image]

Comment: This looks like a bug. Please create an issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KTIJ with a sample project attached and steps to reproduce.

Comment: already done :) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-47914

Comment: @FoxNet that link is broken

Comment: New link https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-20150